How do I count overlapping variables in R?
I am trying to figure out how to get counts for intersectional variables. For example, I have the categorical variables Female, USA and HighIncome and I'm trying to see how many people I have at the intersection of the three.
I haven't been able to find anything comprehensible online.

with(your_df, table(Female, USA, HighIncome))

It's perfect!! You have saved me countless more hours on this simple question. Thank you SO much!!
